# laravel pass parameter to master layout before render?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, view, laravel-5.4

i am making an application and i want that pass error parameters to master view use within partial blade called error.blade.php.

i am checking some variable in controller and if anything occur error i added it to error array as below :

> $error[] = 'error 1';

and i want to pass this to partial blade view called error.blade.php and render it but how can i do this ?

> this array could be empty or not.

how can i pass this array to master layout before render ?

i use this error array every controller.

please help me

Comment: Verify if you have `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,`  in `app/Http/Kernel.php` especially in the `protected $middleware =` array ??

Comment: this error variable which i created not laravel custom error like 404 . ok ?

Comment: i know if `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,` existe thre all you need to do is add `->withErrors($errors)` to `redirect` or `view` methods

Comment: and `$errors` variable will be accessible everywhere in the view even if the master layout !

Comment: it works. thank you so much friend :)

Comment: I will add an answer that you can accept to help other poeple find it because most of them don't read comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) and just pass the data in within the `boot()` method of the provider.

```
    View::composer('master', function ($view) {
       $view->with('errors', $errors);          
    });
```

The `$errors` will be available in your view now.

Comment: errors will change in all controller . how can i edit ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add this line :

```
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

To your `app/Http/Kernel.php` especially in the `protected $middleware =` array

> And all you need to do is add `->withErrors($errors)` to `redirect` or
>   `view` methods and `$errors` variable will be accessible everywhere in
>   the view even if the `master` layout